# how to configure Grizzly Server's maxPostSize

Tags: java, rest, server, webserver, grizzly

I am hitting an error on Grizzly Server :

```
org.glassfish.grizzly.http.HttpCodecFilter handleRead
FINE: Error parsing HTTP header
java.lang.IllegalStateException: HTTP packet header is too large
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.HttpCodecFilter$HeaderParsingState.checkOverflow(HttpCodecFilter.java:1904)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.HttpCodecFilter.decodeHttpPacketFromBytes(HttpCodecFilter.java:662)
```

After a little debugging using the above message `HTTP packet header is too large` was the reason for failure. The header size that I was using was more than the `default 4k size`.

Found this from the [link](http://programmaremobile.blogspot.com/2009/05/request-header-too-large-exception.html).

The link also suggests changing the `maxPostSize` parameter to higher numbers. How can I configure this parameter to higher numbers? I am not finding good help on the web for this.

Comment: Check out the API for [HttpServer](https://grizzly.java.net/docs/2.3/apidocs/org/glassfish/grizzly/http/server/HttpServer.html). You can try to get the NetworkListener and set the max headers size or set max post size. Or you can get the SeverConfiguration, and try to set the same max post size. To make these configurations, you will need to make sure you are creating the `HttpServer`, where it is not starting when created. This should be a boolean flag you can set for one of the factory methods.

Comment: networkListener.setMaxHttpHeaderSize(<sz>);