# Mulesoft Http:Request - Receiving Error: HTTP packet header is too large

Tags: http, mule, mule-studio

I have a mule flow that uses the http:request and this flow is running multiple requests through it at the same time (synchronously). On only a few of the request I will receive the following error:

HTTP packet header is too large (java.lang.IllegalStateException)

The problem here is that the service I am sending the request to receives these like normal and then it blows up in mule so I don't get the correct response that I am looking for.

So in the other system it looks like the call was successful, but on my end it is a failure. I am fairly new to mule so go easy on me lol!

Any and all help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a Mule error message. It looks like people [report this issue with Grizzly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35393910/387927).

I guess Mule sends a header that the server you're calling finds too big. I bet it's the serialized session. If you are using the `http` transport, this can be disabled like this:

```
<http:connector name="NoSessionConnector">
    <service-overrides sessionHandler="org.mule.session.NullSessionHandler"/>
</http:connector>
```

If you are using the new HTTP connector, well, someone else will have to tell you how to disable it...

EDIT: Adding comment from Anirban.

With the new HTTP connector, use:

```
<remove-property propertyName="MULE_SESSION" />
```

to remove the massive session header.

Comment: Hi @David, I guess with new HTTP, we can use `<remove-property propertyName="MULE_SESSION" />` or with **message-properties-transformer** like     `<message-properties-transformer scope="outbound">
    <delete-message-property key="MULE_SESSION" />
</message-properties-transformer>` ...                                                     ref :- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33041725/override-sessionhandler-using-httplistener-config  and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35978104/was-there-a-way-to-remove-mule-session-on-mule-3-7-or-later

Comment: Thanks @AnirbanSenChowdhary

Comment: Thank you both for your responses. So I need to place this inside of the new HTTP connector?

Comment: @DavidDossot I tried placing both 

<remove-property propertyName="MULE_SESSION" />

and

<message-properties-transformer scope="outbound">
    <delete-message-property key="MULE_SESSION" />
</message-properties-transformer>

before the http call and I am still receiving the error when running the project.

Comment: In that case, use a proxy to inspect the HTTP request from Mule and find what exactly is making the receiving end choke. My answer was based on a wild guess, at this point you have to do some forensics.

Comment: @DavidDossot I am fairly new to Mule can you give me any tips on how to do this and what to look for?

Comment: What I'm suggesting has nothing to do with Mule. Using your favorite proxy (like TCPDump) or packet inspector (like WireShark) should work. Then check each HTTP header for anything out of the ordinary.

Comment: Oh alright. I will give that a shot. Thanks @DavidDossot